# How do I make an IOS app *require* DNSSec?

Tags: security, ios, networking, iphone

I need to make sure my IOS app requires DNSSec when it connects to a given server.  How can I make sure the DNS calls are always using this?

Comment: Looks like ios doesn't support dnssec yet. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingConcepts/AddressingSchemesandDomainNames/AddressingSchemesandDomainNames.html

Comment: Just curious, why do you want this?

Comment: @Mike My iOS users use Wifi, and [it's easy to get hacked (link)](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6827/396)

Comment: I assume you have already set up SSL? Because even if your DNS queries always return a correct response, your session data could still be transparently proxied and modified.

Comment: @Mike Yep, I'm aware.  Check the links in my profile.  DNSSec will allow me to verify keys published in DNS even if a SSL attack is underway

Comment: I understand why one wouldn't trust the massive global CA infrastructure, but why not use one of the SSL APIs that allows you to embed the CA certificate into your app?

Comment: Another option might be to use your own DNSSEC client in-app, and then change the SSL API usage to refer to the IP address returned from your DNSSEC client, rather than a DNS name. This assumes you don't have any `Host:` header requirements, and also requires the [considered bad, I think] practice of having your IP address in your server certificate's subjectAlternateName.

Comment: (still not sure how you'd use DNSSEC to prevent an SSL attack if the attacker redirects the client to a site with a hijacked certificate without poisoning DNS. I really think your only option is to double check that you trust CA certificate; that it's the CA you think it is.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to incorporate a DNS library to your source code. Try using libunbound. With libunbound you can verify the DNSSEC answer. With that, you can try to use DANE for securing your SSL certificate.

Comment: But how would you go about using a high-level (for example) HTTP API using this method? Once you send in the URL, it's all over. You can't compare the DNS replies for accuracy. You can't even send in `http://<ip-address/` after doing a DNS query, because you'll lose the `Host: ` header. (etc)

Comment: If your high-level HTTP library does not support DNSSEC, then you need to do the DNS lookup yourself (using unbound) and then if the result validates, issue the command using the HTTP API. Note you can not use the domain in the HTTP request as the HTTP library will probably do the DNS lookup the non-DNSSEC way and if the domain is dns poisoned, the library would still connect to the rogue site.  You need to pass the IP address that you validated to the HTTP library (and use/add a Host header if needed)

Answer (score 1):

DNSSEC is available on the OS level with iOS 10+ as part of the [dnssd Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd). You use it by using the [kDNSServiceFlagsValidate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1823436-anonymous/kdnsserviceflagsvalidate?language=occ) flag when querying the DNS using [DNSServiceQueryRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804747-dnsservicequeryrecord).

If you want to secure your TLS connection you have to implement the dns query in [URLSessions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession) `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` method.

However, you should be aware that there are public dns servers out there (like i.e. OpenDNS), that [do not support DNSSEC](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/).

Answer (score 0):

Since [DNSSEC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4033) is not available at the OS level, I think the best option you have is to secure your app by checking your SSL server cerficiate more carefully than the OS naturally would. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103568/how-to-retrieve-the-ssl-server-certificate-in-ios) for details. I would recommend embedding the CA certificate you expect to receive into your app, and comparing it byte-for-byte with the root of the trust chain.

This is called [certificate pinning](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/blog/authenticity-is-broken-in-ssl-but-your-app-ha/).

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 16+ you can now use [`requiresDNSSECValidation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwparameters/3952717-requiresdnssecvalidation?changes=latest_major). You can set it on `URLSessionConfiguration` or `URLRequest`.

**On URLSessionConfiguration:**

```swift
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.requiresDNSSECValidation = true

let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
```

**On URLRequest:**

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.requiresDNSSECValidation = true
```

Answer (score -1):

DNSSec is on the OS level.  The only thing you can control in your app is the method of connection to your server.  Just use [Secure Sockets Layer - SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) in all your communication.